# How to parallelize the row wise Pandas dataframe's apply() method

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

def enrich_str(str):
        
    val1 = f'{str}_1'
    val2 = f'{str}_2'
    val3 = f'{str}_3'
    time.sleep(3)
    
    return val1, val2, val3
    
def enrich_row(passed_row):
    col_name = str(passed_row['colName'])
    my_string = str(passed_row[col_name])
    
    val1, val2, val3 = enrich_str(my_string)
    
    passed_row['enriched1'] = val1
    passed_row['enriched2'] = val2
    passed_row['enriched3'] = val3
    
    return passed_row


df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'orange', 'red']}, 
                  columns=['numbers', 'colors'])

df['colName'] = 'colors'

tic = time.perf_counter()
enriched_df = df.apply(enrich_row, col_name='colors', axis=1)
toc = time.perf_counter()

print(f"{df.shape[0]} rows enriched in {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")

enriched_df
```

It takes 15 seconds to get the output dataframe like the following one:

[image]

Now I want to parallelize the enrichment operation using multiple threads on my machine.
I explored a lot of solution, like `Dask`, `numba`, but none of them seems strightforward to me.

Then I stumbled upon the `multiprocessing` library and its `pool.imaps()` method. So I tried to run the following code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

tic = time.perf_counter()
pool = mp.Pool(5)
result = pool.imap(enrich_row, df.itertuples(), chunksize=1)
pool.close()
pool.join()
toc = time.perf_counter()

print(f"{df.shape[0]} rows enriched in {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")
result
```

It takes about 2 seconds and `result` isn't a Pandas dataframe.
I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: for i in range(1,4):
    df[f'enriched{i}'] = df.colors + f'_{i}' ??

Comment: @Nk03 I am interested in parallelizing the process, not in a simple loop

Comment: Dask will work smoothly. You can follow examples for `map_partitions`. With that said, you should generally avoid explicit row-wise loops in favor of significantly faster columnar operations, like the suggested loop above.

Comment: I tried before the Dask dataframe's `apply()` method using data read with `read_csv()` (120 rows). It didn't parallelize the process and I didn't understand why. I've just discovered that it didn't parallelize simply because the dataframe's `npartitions` was 1. Repartitioning the dataframe with repartition(npartitions=os.cpu_count()*2) did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use the [pathos fork](https://pypi.org/project/pathos/) of `multiprocessing`, because it will handle pickling the DataFrames better. `imap` returns an iterator, not a DataFrame, so you have to convert it back:

```
def enrich_row(row_tuple):
    passed_row = row_tuple[1]
    col_name = str(passed_row['colName'])
    my_string = str(passed_row[col_name])
    
    val1, val2, val3 = enrich_str(my_string)
    
    passed_row['enriched1'] = val1
    passed_row['enriched2'] = val2
    passed_row['enriched3'] = val3
    
    return passed_row

df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'orange', 'red']}, 
                  columns=['numbers', 'colors'])

df['colName'] = 'colors'

from pathos.multiprocessing import Pool

tic = time.perf_counter()
result = Pool(8).imap(enrich_row, df.iterrows(), chunksize=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
toc = time.perf_counter()

print(f"{df.shape[0]} rows enriched in {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")
print(df)
```

Note that I'm using `df.iterrows()` which returns an iterator of tuples `(row_number, row)`, so I modified `enrich_row` to handle this format.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, @albert. I expect that parallelization will take about 3-4 seconds to do all the stuff. I run your code, but it is still running after 1 minute... Any bug in `pathos`?

Comment: I confirm it keeps running indefinitely. I was forced to kill the process.

Comment: I don't know, this finishes in 3 seconds on my machine. Are you running it on a different dataframe than the one in the post?

Comment: Nope, I'm running it using the same dataframe using VS Code on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted @albert's answer as it works on Linux. Anyway I found the [Dask dataframe's `apply()` method](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.apply) really strightforward. As I mentioned in a previous comment, at first the operation was not performed in parallel on a dataset of 120 rows. I later discovered that the 120 rows used only one partition of the Dask dataframe. Therefore it was sufficient to do a repartition to obtain the desired parallelism. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67482756/416988) an example of the code using Dask (which is raising some strange warnings...).